# Display created_at from pivot table in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a three tables - attendees, messages and attendee_message. When a users is sent a standardized message a record is added to the pivot table attendee_message with the id of the attendee, the id of the message and a date/time stamp in the created_at field.

My issue is that both the attendees and messages tables have a field called created_at and when I go to display the date/time the message was sent (the created_at from the attendee_message column) it displays the created_at from the messages table. How do I display the created_at from the attendee_message table instead?

The function that gets the attendees, a scope and the relationship from the model:

```
    public function getatts() {
        $atts = Attendee::cmo()->orderBy('created_at');
        $atts = $atts->paginate(25);
        return $atts;
    }

    public function scopeCmo($query)
    {
        return $query->where('block_id', '=', 3);
    }

    public function messages() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Message','attendee_message','attendee_id','message_id')
            ->withPivot('id');
    }
```

From my list.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($att->messages as $message)
    <li>'{{$message->subject}}' sent {{$message->created_at}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the row in the pivot table you can use the `pivot` property. [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)

```
$message->pivot->created_at
```

However, by default there are only keys present in the pivot object. So you will need to do

```
->withPivot('created_at');
```

on the relationship. In your case it would be `->withPivot('id', 'created_at')` if you want to have `id` in there as well